Is my proof that "everything exists" correct?
Let $E(x)$ mean that $x$ exists. Then the proposition $∀x(E(x))$ means "everything exists."
Its negation is $∃x(¬E(x)),$ and means "something that doesn't exist exists." This is a contradiction, and thus false.
Therefore, the original proposition "everything exists" is true.
Is the above argument valid?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Let $E(x)$ mean that $x$ exists.

Your first mistake is this ambiguous definition.
Instead, let $Ex$ mean, for example, that $x$ physically exists.
Alternatively, $Ex \overset{\text{def}}\Longleftrightarrow∃y\,y=x,$ in which case $Ex$ means that $x$ exists in the discourse domain.

the proposition $∀x\,Ex$ means "everything exists."
Its negation is $∃x\,¬Ex,$ and means "something that doesn't exist exists."

Observe that your translation has two plausible readings, neither of which is faithful to $∃x\,¬Ex,$ and both of which telegraph your invalid argument's conclusion:

A thing that doesn't exist exists
Anything that doesn't exist exists
$\forall x\,(\lnot Ex \to Ex)$

Some thing that doesn't exist exists
$\exists x\,(\lnot Ex \land Ex).$


On the other hand, here are several accurate translations of $∃x\,¬Ex:$

There is a thing that doesn't "exist"
Some thing doesn't "exist"
There exists a thing that doesn't "exist"
Something doesn't "exist".

I'm using quotation marks to distinguish the currently ambiguously defined predicate $Ex$ (whose definition varies with the chosen interpretation) from the quantifier $\exists x,$ which means neither $\text‘x$ physically exists’ nor $\text‘x$ exists in the discourse domain’ $(∃y\,y=x)$ nor ‘the discourse domain is nonempty’ $(∃x\,x=x).$

This is a contradiction

The sentence $∃x\,¬Ex$ (and its negation the original sentence $\forall x\,∃x)$ is invalid but satisfiable; so, it isn't a contradiction.
To see how $∃x\,¬Ex$ can be true, let the discourse domain be all imaginary things, the predicate $Ex$ mean that $x$ physically exists, and put $x=$ unicorn.
Ultimately, whether $∀x\,Ex$ is true or false depends on the chosen interpretation (the discourse domain and the definition of $Ex).$

There is a thing that doesn't "exist"= there exist a thing that doesnt exist

imaginal exist, and physical exist is different

@Displayname The point is that Ex's meaning varies with the interpretation, whereas ∃x is a pair of logical symbols that cannot be read along the lines of "x exists" or "something exists". I've just expanded the answer to elaborate.

If your statement is intended to be “$\forall x$, $x$ exists”, then that might be true or false. Every $\forall$ statement has a universe of objects-under-discussion associated with it, and that universe is undefined here. If it's meant to be “all things that exist”, then the statement is true, but doesn't assert that all (possible) things exist. If the universe is meant to be “all possible things”, then the statement is false and thus doesn't give a contradiction.

Your proof is right in the appropriate context, which I consider to be a first-order classical theory with a predicate symbol $E(x)$ and the axiom "$\lnot \exists x (\lnot E(x))$", which you seem to be using implicitly. Tell me if this is what you were looking for.
However, it might be more appropriate to use a logic of definedness or existence. In the former, we have an axiom $E(x)$ and a rule for the introduction of universal quantification that allows us to prove $\forall x (E(x)).$ The interpretation is that the domain of discourse only contains existing things; there may be undefined terms, but they don't correspond to anything and can't be substituted for $x$ (think of $\frac10$). For example, the domain could contain all existing animals but not unicorns (although this is very open to interpretation).
According to the more informal survey in the paper, the same result should be true in existence logic, using $E(x) \to E(x)$ and universal introduction restricted to existing stuff. But the interpretation is not as clear to me.

I am unable to judge due to my lack of ability.
